# Что такое "кока с соком" (значение и происхождение фразеологизма)?

Tags: фразеология

Фразеологизм устаревший, в современной литературе не встречается. Но интересно то, что у него **вроде бы нет определенного значения, да и происхождение неясное.**

Что это, присказка-приговорка?

Примеры:

― Давайте на дорогу **коку с соком** выпьем, сказал Минин, вылезая из авто. [А. В. Чаянов. Путешествие моего брата Алексея в страну крестьянской утопии (1920)]

...они ахнут, увидя эти деньги, теперь и у меня есть **кока с соком**, авось хоть этим я приду старосте по сердцу. [П. А. Плавильщиков. Бобыль (1790)]

Он вам покажет **коку с соком!** [Максим Горький. Жизнь Клима Самгина. Часть 2 (1928)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кокой раньше называли яйцо. Пишут, что было такое старинное кушанье кока с соком — яйца с толчеными семенами конопли (правда, неясно, причем тут сок). А значение действительно неопределеное. По-моему, можно заменить на "этакая штука" с таким же неопределенным значением (значение становится ясно из контекста).

У [Ушакова](http://feb-web.ru/feb/ushakov/ush-abc/11/us1d9517.htm?cmd=0&istext=1):

> КО'КА1, и, ж., и ко́ко, а, ср. (детск.). Яйцо. ◊ Кока с соком — шутливая поговорка, обозначающая нечто неожиданное или неприятное, странное и пр.

В других словарях:

[Кока с соком](https://phraseology.academic.ru/5484/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC), [Кока с соком](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/25764/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Мне кажется, что это устаревшая приговорка  на все случаи жизни вроде нашей  присказки "печки-лавочки". Интересная у них судьба: неожиданно появляются, живут в языке некоторое время, а потом уходят так же неожиданно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой напиток - Кока- Кола, первая часть его названия происходит от растения, чьи листья изначально входили в состав газировки. Впоследствии,  это растение признали наркотическим, запретили, а  сок листьев "коки" в напитке заменился кофеином. В конце 19-го, начале 20-го веков,  кокаин был весьма популярен в СПб и Москве и называли его "кока". КОКАИН же - научное название очищенного вещества, применявшегося в лекарственных целях. В первую мировую войну и, впоследствии, в гражданскую был распространён "балтийский чай" - спирт с кокой, либо водка с тем же, пили его матросы, как правило, а офицеры вполне могли употреблять с соком. Что касается 18-го века. - С растением Европу познакомили испанские завоеватели ещё в 16-ом веке.
  Подведу итог.  Вероятнее всего, до 19-го века в данном выражении подразумевали яйцо, но к началу века 20-го вполне могла произойти семантическая трансформация, - атмосфера послереволюционной России тому способствовала.

Comment: Кока с соком упоминается в источниках 18-го века, так что версия про кокаин — ложная.

Comment: @М_Г Почему? ["Считается, что первым листья коки в Европу доставил в 1505 году Америго Веспуччи."](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: @avp Читаем дальше: "В 1859 году из них был выделен препарат, получивший название кокаин". Tолько в конце 19-го века! Не думаете ли вы, что до тех пор на Руси жевали листья коки и об этом слагали поговорки?

Comment: По крайне мере, все на Руси знали, что такое кока (яйцо) и сок.  А если бы употребляли повсеместно, то не было бы поговорки, ведь она — о чем-то странном, необычном.

Comment: @М_Г, не думаю, думаю что кока -- яйцо это правильно. Речь же в комментарии о том, что *формально* слово **кока** (листья, конечно) могло быть известно в России 18-го века

Comment: @avp Квас на улицах парижа и листья коки в русских поговорках...  Если вам такие версии кажутся правдоподобными, а Ушаков по-вашему ошибался, то  спорить больше не берусь. Может, и Земля не круглая, и на Луне никто не побывал. Сторонников этих теорий не переспоришь.

Comment: @М_Г, с тем, что **кока -- яйцо это правильно**, я и не спорю (см. выше). А вообще, странная у вас, гуманитариев, логика... Думаю, на это закончим.

Comment: После того, как вопрос был дополнен, я убрал минус.

Comment: @avp Должен извиниться, я понял Вас с точностью до наоборот, там был такой непонятный текст: "не думаю, думаю что кока -- яйцо это правильно"

Comment: @М_Г, все ОК, не беспокойтесь